# Exception caused by @OneToMany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

please can any one help me to find a solution to this problem. 
It seems that in Hibernate there is a problem with `@OneToMany` annotation when there are more than one collection to fecth.
 When i try to do so, it gives this exception `Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`.

And this is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game", catalog = "competition_manager")
public class Game implements java.io.Serializable {
    private List<GamePlayerGoals> gamePlayerGoalses = new ArrayList<GamePlayerGoals>(0);
    private List<GamePlayer> gamePlayers = new ArrayList<GamePlayer>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "game")
    public List<GamePlayerGoals> getGamePlayerGoalses() {
        return this.gamePlayerGoalses;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "game")
    public List<GamePlayer> getGamePlayers() {
        return this.gamePlayers;
    }
}
```

But my question is : Is it impossible to fetch more than OnetoMany annotated collection in Hibernate? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hibernate has already told you what the problem is.**

You can't `EAGER`ly fetch more than 1 "many" collection at once. This is because the collection is joined into the query Hibernate uses internally.

Joining more than one collection in this would would require a "cartesian product" resultset to be queried, fetching N * M rows -- very inefficient when only N+M+1 are required. (N for players, M for goals or whatever).

Pick one collection you want EAGER & turn it off for the other.  And next time, try reading the error message.

Comment: thank for your reply. Be sure i red the error message and i understood it very well. But my question is : Is it impossible to fetch more than OnetoMany annotated collection in Hibernate?

Comment: You should add that question to your Question

Comment: Since there isn't good SQL to achieve this, Hibernate does not support it and presumably never will support it. You can retrieve as many collections as you like, non-eagerly.

Comment: @Benjamin Schwalb: ok